# Attoparsec: skipping up to (but not including) a multi-char delimiter

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I have a string that can contain pretty much any character. Inside the string there is the delimiter `{{{`.

For example: `afskjdfakjsdfkjas{{{fasdf`.

Using attoparsec, what is the idiomatic way of writing a `Parser ()` that skips all characters before `{{{`, but without consuming the `{{{`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13202371/2541573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `attoparsec`'s `lookAhead` (which applies a parser without consuming any input) and `manyTill` to write a parser that consumes everything up to (but excluding) a `{{{` delimiter. You're then free to apply that parser and throw its result away.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative ( (<|>) )
import Data.Text ( Text )
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator ( lookAhead, manyTill )

myParser :: Parser Text
myParser = T.concat <$> manyTill (nonOpBraceSpan <|> opBraceSpan)
                                 (lookAhead $ string "{{{")
                    <?> "{{{"
  where
    opBraceSpan    = takeWhile1 (== '{')
    nonOpBraceSpan = takeWhile1 (/= '{')
```

In GHCi:

```
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings 
λ> parseTest myParser "{foo{{bar{{{baz"
Done "{{{baz" "{foo{{bar"
```

Comment: What is the rationale behind using `(nonOpBraceSpan <|> opBraceSpan)` instead of `anyChar`?

Comment: @levantpied I wrote this answer a while ago... and I can't remember :) I'd have to retest it to see whether using `anyChar` changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the slightly harder way like this:

```
foo = many $ do
  Just c <- fmap (const Nothing) (try $ string "{{{") <|> fmap Just anyChar
  return c
```

Or you could use this helper function [`manyTill`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v:manyTill) like this:

```
foo = manyTill anyChar (try $ string "{{{")
```

Comment: That doesn't leave the `{{{` unconsumed, though.

Comment: You're right. And I can't see anything in the attoparsec docs that would help with that directly. But what you can do is write the next part of the parser knowing that it will never be reached unless `{{{` is found.

Comment: @JeremyList Note that `try` is just `id` in attoparsec. [*This combinator is provided for compatibility with Parsec. Attoparsec parsers always backtrack on failure.*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.2.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#g:7)

Comment: Good to know. When I rolled my own parser combinators I didn't include `try` for the same reason.